# Ruby Range test case SyntaxError

Tags: arrays, ruby, testing, range

I'm running Ruby's [`Range` test case](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/test/ruby/test_range.rb#L38) but got an error in the line:

```
assert_equal([*"a".."z", "aa"], ("a"..).take(27))
```

The error message is:

```
test/ruby/test_range.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...qual([*"a".."z", "aa"], ("a"..).take(27))
...                              ^
```

I also tried `('a'..)` in `irb` and got a SyntaxError:

```
irb> ('a'..)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /home/sergioro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
SyntaxError ((irb):9: syntax error, unexpected ')')
('a'..)
```

My question is what is `('a'..)`? This syntax is used several times in the test case but it is not described in [Range's documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html).

---

**Update:**

Installing Ruby version 2.6.4 solved the error for `('a'..)`. But there is an error if the endless range is on the left, like in [test_range.rb:536](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/test/ruby/test_range.rb#L536):

```
assert_operator(..'Z', :===, 'ANA')
```

The error is:

```
test_range.rb:536: syntax error, unexpected .., expecting ')'
    assert_operator(..'Z', :===, 'ANA')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('a'..)` is [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges) introduced in [ruby 2.6](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/07/04/ruby-2-6-adds-endless-range.html). You need to install Ruby 2.6  and run this test on ruby 2.6.

Comment: please add the line with left endless range

Comment: I included the new error in the question and accepted this answer for my original question.

Comment: Endless range without begin seem not to be supported in 2.6: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges. Note that you link tests to trunk ruby, not to 2.6